# Choose password for new keyring

Tags: 11.04, security, keyrings, gnome-keyring

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04, after login it displays this message:

> **Choose password for new keyring**
>
> An application wants to create a new
>   keyring called 'Default'. Choose
>   password you want to use for it.

System is just hanged...not able to do anything. [Except the terminal login using (alt+ctr+f1)].

What is the keyring is all about? How to get rid of it? I'm stuck here.

I have removed the file keyring file @ home/.gnome2/keyring...still the issue remains.

Could you please tell me command based solution...[I tried with seahorse, however "terminal can not open display"] and i dont want to restart the system.

Comment: If your system is hanging, I'd guess that the keyring message is not necessarily related to your hang. Does it work on a live cd? Did it ever work before? Is it a fresh install? Are you using Unity? And include links to your [system log files](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) (post them on pastie.org).

Answer (score 5):

Keyring is used by applications to store your passwords and cryptographic keys in secure manner. It must be protected, either by separate password or being unlocked when you login (with password).

You can manage your keyrings by going to `System Settings` -> `Passwords and Encryption Keys`

See also: [**GNOME Keyring** in wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Keyring)

Answer (score 0):

Well, how would i'll do it on terminal ?
I tried "seahorse", but it wont open on terminal...i want to get rid of it [ i need to do 'esc' always to get rid of it after login].

Comment: You shouldn't add comments as an answer. Add a comment or edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

seahorse is not installed by default with Xubuntu 11.4, you have to install it first. Then you'll find the menu item under "Settings".